# how to extract child's text data using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-crawler, phpquery

i want to extract data 'AT401726' from the html given below

```
<td class="publicationInfoColumn">
  <h4>Publication info:</h4>
  AT401726<br>2008-08-15
</td>
```

& i solved it by using JQuery, the working code is given below

```
('body').find('.publicationInfoColumn').clone().children().remove().end().text()
```

is there any other better technique to extract data from above given html ? there are many html like above in my crawled html page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you are looking for the the contents of the next sibling element of the h4 element, so try

```
var text = $.trim($('.publicationInfoColumn h4').prop('nextSibling').nodeValue);
console.log(text)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uALf9/)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('td.publicationInfoColumn').text();//for text
```

or

```
$('td.publicationInfoColumn').html();//for html
```

Comment: html will include the header

Comment: above code will give >> Publication info:AT4017262008-08-15 but i want only AT401726

Answer (score 0):

You're not *supposed* to be able to target specific text nodes like that. The best you can probably do is:

```
$('.publicationInfoColumn').html().match(/\b.*(?=<br>)/)
```